# My samsung s21 locked and showing too many incorrect attempts...also phone in a flight mode how to resolve this issue pls help?

Tags: locked-out

My samsung s21 locked and showing too many incorrect attempts...also phone in a flight mode how to resolve this issue pls help? Is factory reset is only last option ?

Comment: Do you know your PIN code? Had you had a chance to enter it? How long does your phone show the "too many incorrect attempts" message?

Comment: I know my pin but suddenly it is showing incorrect and after try next try in 24 HR later

Answer (score 0):

Yes a factory reset is the only option if you don't know your PIN.  Data on your phone is encrypted using this PIN.  If it was easy to bypass it, there would be no point in this security measure.

As far as I know, you can factory reset your locked phone, only if you have linked a Google account to it.  Either  via `Find my Mobile` or by `pressing the volume up/down and power buttons`.